# Don't do tests if external project hasn't changed

Tags: cmake

I have a Cmake application that uses ExternalProject_Add to add nlohmann's json to my project, but every time I compile, it runs every json test, is there a way to make it so the test are only done if a new version is downloaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Since you wish to do so only when a new update is available then it is not straightforward. You could probably **hack it** by defining your own `UPDATE_COMMAND` for the target project which would then create a file (or you could try and log the update process) and then by adjusting `CMAKE_ARGS` you could add the option `-DJSON_BuildTests=ON` by configuring step options. You can check this [docu-link for more info.](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html)

That all being said IIRC there is no easy way to do what you want. You can always build it afterwards on your own, which might be easier than doing it in such an "automatic" way.

---

With `nlohmann` I vaguely remember there being a specific issue with this one variable that was discussed and later fixed. Specifically it was the `JSON_BuildTests` variable. So if you:

```
set(JSON_BuildTests OFF)`
```

**before you add the project** - it shouldn't run any tests.

Comment: it's good enough for me but I would like it to make tests if a new version is downloaded

Comment: @Seldron333 as far as I am aware of there is no easy way. I outlined a possible hack for you in the answer. I would however recommend to just build it yourself if you know there's going to be a new version. The whole idea that you run unit tests during the build of an external dependency is just alien to me. The tests should be mainly for developers who wish to change something in the dependency, the end-user should always get a test-passing product, nlohmann is taking a non-standard approach in this case.